# Is is possible to edit an excel workbook that has been emailed as the body of an Outlook email

Tags: excel, outlook, ms-office, vba

I'm trying to find an easy way to disseminate an excel template to a group of people and them input some data and then email the updated template back to me.
One alternative that I've investigated is sending the excel template as the body of an outlook email and then have the users make there input and email it back.

I came across this [article that explains how to email a workbook as the body of an outlook email](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1355-excel-send-sheet-by-email.html#a1). The process works great, however, it appears the emailed spreadsheet can not be edited by the recipient.

Question:
**Is it possible to not only email the workbook/template as a body of an outlook email, but also make the template editable so the recipient can input data into select cells.

Comment: I would probably try [to colaborate](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/) using [Excel online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx?omkt=en-US#).

Comment: That method of sending a **sheet** as the body of an outlook email, actually converts the range to HTML format. The recipient will be able to edit the (all) data if they reply to the email, but the response will also be in HTML format (you'll need to copy and paste it back into the Excel file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot make edits and forward the changes when working in the message body (or with a file previewer).

An alternative is to open the email with the attachment and put the email into Edit mode.  You can then open the attachment, make changes and save, then save the email and forward it.